# Excel Countifs vs count

Tags: excel

If I type =count(LEDGERF!O:O,"D2332")

I get 554

If I type =COUNTIFS(LEDGERF!O:O,"D2332")

I get 0

Why doesn't the countifs work? I am trying to use this with more variables, but need this simple piece to work first.

Comment: Is `D332`a cell reference or a text value? If it's the former then remove the quotes for `COUNTIFS` to work

Answer (score 2):

> The **COUNT** function counts the number of cells that contain numbers, and counts numbers within the list of arguments. Use the COUNT function to get the number of entries in a number field that is in a range or array of numbers. For example, you can enter the following formula to count the numbers in the range A1:A20:
>
> `=COUNT(A1:A20)`
>
> In this example, if five of the cells in the range contain numbers, the result is 5.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `COUNT(value1, [value2], ...)`

Your formula `=count(LEDGERF!O:O,"D2332")` is returning 554 because there are 554 values in the range O:O and does not take into acccount the string `D2332` as it is not a value.

> The **COUNTIFS** function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)`

Your formula `=COUNTIFS(LEDGERF!O:O,"D2332")` counts the number of times the string `D2332` is in the range O:O, which looks to be zero times.

Please let me know if this helps.  If you want to add sample data and expected results to your question, I may be able to help further.